# Wordpress PHP dynamic menu item using shortcode

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, shortcode

This is my menu item structure:

[image]

Here's the code im using to create shortcodes to add dynamic menu items:

```
function my_dynamic_menu_items($menu_items)
{
foreach ($menu_items as $menu_item) {
    if ('#short_code#' === $menu_item->url) {

    }
}
return $menu_items;
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_objects', 'my_dynamic_menu_items');


function my_custom_menu_item($items, $args)
{
preg_match_all('#<li[^"]*"menu-item-([^"]*)" class="shortcode ([^"]*)"><a[^"]*"[^"]*" href="([^"]*)">[^<]*</a></li>#', $items, $x);
if (count($x[0])) {
    foreach ($x[0] as $key => $value) {
        $items = str_replace($value,'<li id="menu-item-'.$x[1][$key].'" class="shortcode '.$x[2][$key].'">'.do_shortcode("[".str_replace("#","",$x[3][$key])."]").'</li>',$items);
    }
}
 return $items;
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'my_custom_menu_item', 10, 2);


function show_places_func($atts)
{
global $my_category_slug;
return "<span><a href='/".$my_category_slug."/local/impacts'>PLACES</a></span>";
}
add_shortcode( 'show_places', 'show_places_func' );
```

The issue is that only works for single menu items(no child/subitems). How can I make parent and child items dynamic? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your regular expression is too strict.  It needs to be modified in order to "pick up" the child menu elements.  I'm no regex expert, but that's definitely the source of the issue.

Comment: Try doing this with a html dom library like http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm , good chance it will solve it